# How represent in printf a variable type unsigned long

Tags: c, printf

To print a var of int in printf you have to %i or %d but what should i add for an unsigned long

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf

Answer (score 1):

`%lu` is the correct format specifier for an `unsigned long`

Answer (score 1):

%lu is the correct format for unsigned long.